# Enable ligatures with Fira Code in PDF output of Rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, yaml, pandoc, ligature

The following code enables me to use [**Fira Code**](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) as mono font.

````
---
monofont: "Fira Code"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
x <- 1:5
x != 2
```
````

This produces the desired ligature for `!=` but not for `<-`.

[image]

The solution detailed in the accepted answer in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294362/use-fira-code-font-with-ligatures-in-code-listings) works when done in LaTeX, e.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmonofont[Contextuals={Alternate}, Scale=0.75, Ligatures=TeX]{Fira Code}
\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@nolig@list{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
x <- 1:5
x != 2
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The following YAML does not work.

```
---
monofont: "Fira Code"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes: |
  \makeatletter
  \def\verbatim@nolig@list{}
  \makeatother
---
```

Can enabling ligatures be done directly in the YAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the generated LaTeX output you see that the curly braces have been quoted: `\def\verbatim@nolig@list\{\}`. This quoting issue has been discussed in several issues on github, and there seems to be a fix available (c.f. [this issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2139)), but I have not tested it since my Debian testing machine still uses pandoc 1.19.2.4. As a workaround you can place the necessary commands into a separate file, say `preamble.tex`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@nolig@list{}
\makeatother
```

and then use

````
---
monofont: "Fira Code"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    include:
      in_header: preamble.tex
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
x <- 1:5
x != 2
```
````

Comment: I was thinking along the line of putting the commands in a separate file. But I haven't thought of looking at the LaTeX output. The quoting is worth exploring.

Comment: @hpesoj626 The quoting issue has been reported and apparently solved, but I cannot test it easily. See the edited answer, where I have also streamlined the solution.

Comment: Thanks, @RalfStubner. I'll be reading the thread. Thanks for the effort, man.

Comment: Any way to do this for word_document output?

Comment: @jzadra I don’t know how to do this with Word.

Comment: @jzadra Are the ligatures in Fira Code compatible with Word in the first place, i.e. independent of using Rmarkdown? I don't have a copy of Word to check and it is not listed in Fira Code's compatibility table.

Comment: @RalfStubner It sure doesn't! Thanks for the suggestion to check on that first.