# Problem with ligatures in Rmarkdown / bookdown pdf output

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown, xelatex, ligature

In my Rmarkdown project, I'm having trouble in correctly exporting ligatures in PDF file.

`font-config.tex` file -

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans}
```

YAML front-matter in Rmd file -

```
---
title: "test"
author: "author"
date: "22/02/2021"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    includes:
      in_header: font-config.tex
---
The following text is in hindi language.

गुरु
```

Output shown in PDF -
[image: Output shown]

Output expected -
[image: Output expected]

The `Nakula` font is correctly displayed, but it does not have bold-face type font.
The `Noto Sans` font I'm using works fine in html output, but have problem with ligature in PDF output.

I tried, the pandoc documentation and other [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074465/enable-ligatures-with-fira-code-in-pdf-output-of-rmarkdown) on stackoverflow and tex.stackexchange, but no luck.
I'm new to TeX, and hopefully it has a very simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you, following the information given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183174/how-can-i-make-hindi-pdf-document-in-latex-without-transliteration?newreg=5aaf999f38334631906d2db6c47de5e6):

```
---
title: "Hindi"
author: "bttomio"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{fontspec}
  - \setmainfont{Noto Sans}
  - \usepackage{polyglossia}
  - \setdefaultlanguage{hindi}
  - \setotherlanguage{english}
  - \newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Nakula}
  - \newfontfamily\devtransl[Mapping=DevRom]{Times New Roman}
---

The following text is in hindi language.

गुरु
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Can you display the Hindi text in bold? With `Nakula` font the ligatures are working fine (but no bold text, because nakula doesn't have a bold type). `Noto Sans` on the otherhand offers regular, italics, bold but faces ligature problem.